# Can't make any list in C#

Tags: c#

I can't figure out what is wrong. I run this code in Visual Studio in a C# .Net Console Project. Trying to make a simple list. I am using lists in more complicated code, but it is not working and now I can't get lists of any kind to run.

I get the error message on the line `List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();`

> The type or namespace 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?).

```
namespace Lists
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
            Mylist.Add("a");
            Mylist.Add("b");
            Mylist.Add("c");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an _using System.Collections.Generic_ in the using references?

Answer (score 9):

Include the proper namespace to access the types in it. `List<T>` is contained in the `System.Collections.Generics` namespace so you need to add the following line on top of your program:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

If you don't know which namespace is missing simply press **CTRL** + **.** on the highlighted line and Visual Studio will add it automatically.